# On Error, populate cell and continue with loop

Tags: excel, vba

The following block of code is a loop intended to look for the value of `cell(i, 1)` of `spreadsheet A` in `spreadsheet B` and return a value of `TRUE` if found, `false` if not in `cells(i, 5)`. At the moment, it will error out if it cannot find the value:

```vb
Sub findCell()
    Dim ETLCell As Range
    Dim mifidCell As Range
    Dim last_row_A As Long
    Dim last_row_B As Long
    
    last_row_A = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").UsedRange.rows.Count
    last_row_B = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").UsedRange.rows.Count
    
    'Loop which returns the TRN beside each column
    For i = 2 To last_row_A
        
        Set ETLCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1).Value)
        Set mifidCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        If ETLCell Is Nothing Then
            ETLCell = "BLANK"
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = "False"
        End If
        
        Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 1).Value = ETLCell
        
        If ETLCell = mifidCell Then
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = "True"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can check to see if the variable contains a value after the `.Find` method. Something like `If ETLCell Is Nothing Then ...`. You can either exit the loop, or respond how you need if the variable is nothing.

Comment: @basodre edited the above to incorporate this - should this now work? Just ran and seeing error Type mismatch for ETLCell.

Comment: The issue is that you're putting the value from ETL Cell into a cell before checking if it's nothing. Move the `...Is Nothing...` line of code before the `Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i,1).value = ETLCell` line of code. Let us know if that works.

Comment: Am afraid I'm still seeing the "Type Mismatch" issue...

Comment: Find returns a Range Object not a String, ETLCell is dimmed as a string.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? I took a look at the whole code block. I think the issue is that you declared `Dim EtlCell as String`. Try instead to declare it as a range: `Dim EtlCell as Range`. Then, on the line where you assign the result of `.Find`, change it to `Set EtlCell = Worksheets(....`

Comment: Thanks. Made additional edits but still erroring at the second Set at mifidCell.

Comment: The second `mifidCell` did not have to be changed. You only need to use `Set` when you are assigning an object. In the case of the second line, you are taking the value of the cell, which is a string. Change the original declaration back to `Dim mifidCell as String`. And then remove the word `Set` from the line where you assign the value to `mifidCell`. Did that help?

Comment: @basodre thanks, I think we're almost there - positive tests are working but am still seeing errors when the value does not exist in Spreadsheet B; for example, if ID no.: 123 is in Spreadsheet A but not Spreadsheet B, `Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 1).Value = ETLCell` is highlighted as an error.

Answer (score 1):

### Default Member

On Objects, such as the `Range Object` there is a thing called a [Default Member](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx). In the case of `Range` the default is `.Value`.

```vb
' This example
Range("A1") = 1234

' is the same as this example
Range("A1").Value = 1234
```

Read [vba-trap-default-members](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/) for greater detail as why this a good thing to **avoid** using in your code.

---

### Errors

In your code, you are trying to assign a value to a `Range` object that is `Nothing`, which it would fail as there is no range to assign the value to.

```vb
If ETLCell Is Nothing Then
    ' ETLCell is nothing (aka it's not referecning a cell.)
    ' Therefore you can not assign a value to the non-cell!
    ETLCell = "BLANK"

    ' Same as ETLCell.value = "BLANK"
```

Additionally, you are attempting to set a `Range` object to a `.Value`. This too will fail, as your data types do not line up. To assign this, you must remove `.Value`.

```vb
Dim mifidCell As Range ' Declared as a range

' Unable to set a `Range` to a value. Must remove `.Value`!
Set mifidCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

### Solution

With what you have provided, it's difficult to fully solution this out. But the main thing you need to check is that your ranges exists or not. If they don't, then what values are you going to use, or what logic do you want to apply next.

With that in mind, here is an example with notes to allow you to play around with it... Just be mindful of the possible failure points.

```vb
Sub findCell()
    ' Not used...
    ' Dim last_row_B As Long
    ' last_row_B = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").UsedRange.rows.Count

    Dim last_row_A As Long
    last_row_A = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").UsedRange.rows.Count
    
    ' Loop which returns the TRN beside each column
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To last_row_A
        Dim mifidCell As Range
        Set mifidCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1)
        ' Need to check if this is nothing, as ETLCell relies on
        ' the cell as well.
        If mifidCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Can't get `ETLCell` as it uses the value of `mifidCell`
            ' You can skip this iteration, provide a default value, throw an error,
            ' or something like that.
        End If

        ' This will error if `mifidCell is Nothing`
        Dim ETLCell As Range
        Set ETLCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").Columns("B:B").Find(What:=mifidCell.Value)

        If ETLCell Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = False
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 1).Value = "BLANK"
        Else
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 1).Value = ETLCell.Value
        End If
        
        ' This too will fail if `ETLCell is nothing or mifidCell Is Nothing`
        If ETLCell.Value = mifidCell.Value Then
            Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is super, thanks so much for your input, Robert.